# Crash log from iOs App Store

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I got this initial message from Apple during my app review:

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 9.3.5 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
- Specifically, upon launch, nothing but a static launch screen loaded in your app. No further action appeared possible.
We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.
Next Steps
Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify the issue(s), then revise and resubmit your app for review.

So I asked for a crash log and I got the following output:

```
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott kernel[0] <Notice>: APPLE_PROTECT: 2361[xpcproxy] map 0xffffff811f4aef78 set_code_unprotect(/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FDA59D1C-A9D2-4B9C-AE27-A2D324E17D12/Npact.app/Npact) -> 0x0
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott kernel[0] <Notice>: APPLE_PRap 0xffffff811f4aef78 [0x1000f4000:0x100230000] pager 0xffffff811d5008c0: backing:[object:0xffffff811cf57e00,offset:0x260000,crypto_backing_offset:0x260000,crypto_start:0x0,crypto_end:0x13c000]
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott kernel[0] <Notice>: [2361] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/875F5708-23DF-4944-854F-565073C480D2 (sandbox)
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: launchd.development + 115632 [6326D1AF-0CFD-359D-BD98-AE7C9E7711D0]: 0x3
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott hangtracerd[128] <Warning>: WARNING: Npact(2361) was already being watched.
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott hangtracerd[128] <Warning>: Watching process Npact(2361) idx 27 being launched for 1200.000000ms appState 1
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.0 is starting.
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott coreduetd[119] <Warning>: [context info]: options are {
        kCDCSNotificationOptionClientIdentifierKey = 173;
        kCDCSNotificationOptionEnableForNextStateChangeKey = 1;
        kCDCSNotificationOptionRegisterOnlyKey = 1;
    }
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott coreduetd[119] <Warning>: [context info]: Rule with predicate (FocalApp != ""), launchkey (null) registered
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott coreduetd[119] <Warning>: [context info]: Proxy client remembering predicate id 1349186172899131367 (FocalApp != "")
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott duetexpertd[173] <Warning>: [context info]: ---> Enabling handler : contextual predicate: (FocalApp != "") predicateId = 1349186172899131367
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Using UIWebView
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.074983ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Unlimited access to network resources
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.304030ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.059009ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 10.924995ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.801027ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: VERSION LABEL: 0.1.1:1472677084:
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][ionicdeploy] 0.904024ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 14.818966ms
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: createNotificationChecker
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: not coldstart
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: active
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: PushPlugin skip clear badge
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: uuid is: 
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: ignore version: 
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Resetting plugins due to page load.
Sep  7 01:20:42 Willfred-Mott Npact[2361] <Warning>: Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/FDA59D1C-A9D2-4B9C-AE27-A2D324E17D12/Npact.app/www/index.html
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be? It works fine when I test in on my device, but I don't know how to set up a IPv6 network on my Windows PC.

Comment: This is not a crash report but console log output.

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?